# innerHTML not updating display

Tags: javascript, innerhtml

First, hello everyone as I'm new here.

To summarize my problem, I read the content of an XML file to display in a table.
The basic function to do this works well, I created a derivated function to include a search filter related to an input field.
The search algorithm works well and I'm able to preview the HTML code of the search result using the alert() function and this code seems proper and can be displayed in a browser properly as it would be supposed to. However the innerHTML code of the concerned div is not updated...
I would appreciate any kind of input or solution anyone could provide as I've been stuck on this ! Thanks !

Here is the code :

```
    function printListMod2(){
    //Search parameters ?
    var searchContent = document.getElementById("searchField").value;
    var i=0;

    newHTML = "<table id=\"tableInstrus\">";
    for (i=0;i<listInstrus.length;i++){
        filename = returnFilename(i);
        title = returnTitle(i);
        tempo = returnTempo(i);
        sample = returnSample(i);
        multi = returnMulti(i);
        style1 = returnStyle1(i);
        style2 = returnStyle2(i);

        var regEx = new RegExp(searchContent, 'gi');
        var resultSearch = title.match(regEx);
        if(resultSearch!=null){
            if(i%2==0){
                newHTML += "<tr class=\"tr0\"><td class=\"idColumn\">"+(i+1)+"</td><td class=\"emptyColumn\"></td><td class=\"nameColumn\">"+title+"</td><td class=\"tempoColumn\">"+tempo+"</td><td class=\"sampleColumn\">"+sample+"</td><td class=\"multiColumn\">"+multi+"</td><td class=\"styleColumn\">"+style1+"</td><td class=\"styleColumn\">"+style2+"</td><td class=\"addLink\"><a id="+filename+" onclick=\"addLinkToPlaylist("+i+")\"><img title=\"Add to playlist\" class=\"addButton\" src=\"images/buttonAdd.png\"/></a></td><td class=\"playLink\"><a onclick=\"playTrack("+i+","+true+")\"><img title=\"Play this track\" class=\"playButton\" src=\"images/buttonPlaySmall.png\"/></a></td></tr>";
            }
            else{
                newHTML += "<tr class=\"tr1\"><td class=\"idColumn\">"+(i+1)+"</td><td class=\"emptyColumn\"></td><td class=\"nameColumn\">"+title+"</td><td class=\"tempoColumn\">"+tempo+"</td><td class=\"sampleColumn\">"+sample+"</td><td class=\"multiColumn\">"+multi+"</td><td class=\"styleColumn\">"+style1+"</td><td class=\"styleColumn\">"+style2+"</td><td class=\"addLink\"><a id="+filename+" onclick=\"addLinkToPlaylist("+i+")\"><img title=\"Add to playlist\" class=\"addButton\" src=\"images/buttonAdd.png\"/></a></td><td class=\"playLink\"><a onclick=\"playTrack("+i+","+true+")\"><img title=\"Play this track\" class=\"playButton\" src=\"images/buttonPlaySmall.png\"/></a></td></tr>";
            }
        }
    }
    newHTML += "<tr><td class=\"idColumn\"></td><td id=\"emptyColumn\"></td><td class=\"nameColumn\"></td><td class=\"tempoColumn\"></td><td class=\"sampleColumn\"></td><td class=\"multiColumn\"></td><td></td><td></td></tr>";
    newHTML += "</table>";
    alert(newHTML); //this displays the HTML code properly
    document.getElementById("listDiv").innerHTML = newHTML; //this doesn't seem to do anything...
}
```

Comment: So you're 100% certain that there's an element with the id "listDiv" on the page, right? And that it's CSS is such that its contents are visible?  Have you used the browser DOM inspector to check to see whether the HTML content was actually inserted?

Comment: Depending on the browser, your lack of the tbody tag can cause a problem. I would strongly suggest using a library like jQuery to ease cross browser support problems. Also please be aware that you must escape < and > with &lt; and &gt; repectively, otherwise the XML values will not show up.

Comment: Thank you for your answers, @Pointy yes, the div is present and visible at first, the content is not updated however. The example is online so you might get a better understanding of my issue :http://toxxikmuzik.com/test/index.html, use the search field, press enter and it will give you the alert message but not the updated table.

Comment: @Toxx when I look at your page, the "listDiv" is definitely being populated with your table.  It's hard to see it, but it's there. *edit* wait it's only hard to see it when the page loses focus. Otherwise it looks fine I think. *edit again* wait maybe I'm confused. Is the problem something that happens *after* you search?

Comment: Have you noticed that when you do a search, you get an error from your "printPlaylist" function? Something's trying to update the class name of a table row, but the table row isn't being found.

Comment: @Pointy thanks for checking. The "printPlaylist" function gives an error indeed but it is not called at all in the process of searching for a title. The problem is that the listDiv is never updated with the proper HTML code, basically the content of the alert message should be display in the listDiv but it's not for some reason I'm trying to figure out.

Answer (score 0):

Is your script being executed before the document has finished loading?
Then it won't find #listDiv because the div doesn't exist yet.

I would check the javascript console output for errors and check if the following code doesn't return undefined:

```
{
  ...
  console.log( document.getElementById('listDiv') );
}
```

Comment: The container element ("listDiv") seems to be correctly updated as far as I can tell.

Comment: Your code works. When you type 'down' in your search box and you execute printListMod2() in the console, the table gets updated with the filtered results.

I think you trigger printListMod2() by pressing key 13 (enter), but then the page reloads and so does the original content.

Comment: @Flaff I'm confused, why would the page reload ? Is it because of pressing the "enter" key ? I use the same function with select tags for other filters and it refreshes the div innerHTML content properly.

Comment: It updates because it's a (far) child of 'form action onchange="printListMod()"'. It invokes a submit action which refreshes the page. When i change the form to a div, it updates like it should..

Comment: EDIT
It doesn't work completely yet, you have to press enter twice.  I think it's rather a problem of multiple functions triggering, than the function you had questions about in your OP.

Comment: You are right indeed, I just checked and whether the focus is on the input field or not, if I press enter, it will trigger my function... I will investigate more on that. Thanks.